# Solving Higher Order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I have to solve the following differential equation using the substitution $$u = y'$$

$$yy''+(y')^2 + 1 = 0 $$

But how do I integrate after simplifying the substitution if I cannot separate the variables?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{1}{2}[y^2]'' = yy'' + (y')^2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

Let: $$u(y)=\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx}$$

Then: 
$$
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{du(y)}{dx}=\dfrac{du(y)}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=u'(y)y'
$$